# Image src set but not seen on my page

Tags: css, image

For some reason if you access [my blog](http://indulgent.mrldesign.co.uk), via the blog snippet at the bottom of my home page, no images show in the footer and header, this is the same accessing through the archive section. I'm hoping its a simple issue I've overlooked.

I used this method of integrating a wordpress blog in my html site. 
http://newjerseygraphicdesign.com/wordpress/how-to-integrate-a-wordpress-blog-into-an-existing-website-2011/2/

I'm now stuck with this issue. Strangely enough, if you access the blog page via the nav bar, all images are visible.

If anyone could help me, my test site is at http://indulgent.mrldesign.co.uk It's not yet completed so final content and styling has to be done.

Cheers in advance,
Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this in your markup:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/295x295">
```

which has problem in its `src` because `295x295` is not a proper file name

**UPDATE**

as u mentioned in comments problem is on [this page](http://indulgent.mrldesign.co.uk/blog/2015/07/14/hello-world/). On the page you have this markup for one of the images not shown visually:

```
<img src="../img/logo.svg" class="logo center-block img-responsive">
```

if you get that src link it would be:

```
http://indulgent.mrldesign.co.uk/blog/2015/07/14/img/logo.svg
```

meaning that the browser expects the `logo.svg` be in this address and because it is not, it can not show it up!!!

As you have noticed by this moment, you should change the `src` from

```
src="../img/logo.svg"
```

to some other correct value to address the image.

Comment: I should have been clearer, my issue isn't with my placeit image.  Its with the wordpress blog.  If you scroll down and click the blog snippet the page shows without images.
cheers

Comment: what do u mean by blog snippet?

Comment: The snippet of the blog, which can be seen in the lower part of the index.php home page.  Its marked as an example blog post. "14th July - Hello World"

Comment: Where is exactly this image `instagram.png`? in themes folder?

Comment: Its not within the theme folder, its linked up a file to the [code]../img[code] folder

Comment: Where is that image on your folder structure?

Comment: Images are all stored with /img folder

Comment: where is that folder? R U crazy ?

Comment: Am I missing something here?  The /img folder is on the server in the root directory.

Comment: Please check my answer in a minute. I will update it

Comment: Okay, thanks I understand now.  I'll try re linking the src files in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome to view your page.

Go to the page that has the error.  Right click on the image/element with a problem.  Choose "inspect element".

Chrome reveals that the path to the image is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have done this, and still can't see where the issue would be.  Its an issue with the wordpress element somewhere.

Comment: The link on your page `<a href="/blog">Blog</a>` that displays your images ... the link `<a href="http://indulgent.mrldesign.co.uk/blog/2015/07/14/hello-world/" title="Hello world!"> Hello world!</a>` does not.

You will need to correct the path to your images in WordPress for your blog posts.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've tried to locate the post to find where it it within the wordpress install, but can't.  I guess this is the problem I have right now.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to upload the pictures for the website to the blog's images folder?

Comment: Doesn't work,  I think its to do with where the blog post sits within the file hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution.  Was really stupidly simple.  I should have linked the image files in a more universal way.
`http://indulgent.mrldesign.co.uk/img/..` 
sorry for wasting everyones time on simple answer.